# My function is not invoked in another function

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I'm trying to get my function to determine singular and plural errors. I wrote two functions in the global scope to be called in the main function called `errorChecker` but it refuses to execute. I'm wondering why? and what it is I am doing wrong. I am really new to coding so, please understand. below is the code. it does not run hence the `errorChecker` function does not detect the errors.

```
function errorChecker (num1, word1, num2, word2) {
  if (num1 === Number(num1) && word1 === String(word1) && num2 === Number(num2) && word2 === String(word2)) {
    console.log('all parameters are ok')
  } else {
    return false
  }
  if (wordChecker(word1) === true && (wordChecker(word2) === true)) {
    return true
  } else {
    console.log('invalid parameter')
  }
  if (singularChecker(num1, word1) === false && (pluralChecker(num2, word2) === false)) {
    console.log('correct singular and plurals')
  } else {
    return true
  }
}
// For checking function effectiveness
const num1 = 1
const word1 = 'minutes'
const num2 = 2
const word2 = 'minute'

console.log(errorChecker(num1, word1, num2, word2))
// function to set exact word parameters that can be used
function wordChecker (word) {
  switch (word) {
    case 'seconds':
    case 'second':
    case 'minutes':
    case 'minute':
    case 'hours':
    case 'hour':
    case 'days':
    case 'day':
      return true
    default:
      return false
  }
}

function pluralChecker (digit, letters) {
  switch (letters.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'seconds':
    case 'minutes':
    case 'hours':
    case 'days':
      if (digit !== 1) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
  }
}

function singularChecker (numz, wordz) {
  switch (wordz.lowerCase()) {
    case 'second':
    case 'minute':
    case 'hour':
    case 'day':
      if (numz === 1) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the browser, it may be that you're attempting to call functions before they're defined (top to bottom).

This code seemed to run fine for me in Firefox on Windows.

However, I see a lot of room for improvement in your coding style.

Add a `console.log` to each function to see if and when it runs, and what you sent into it.

Move the line `console.log(errorChecker(num1, word1, num2, word2))` to the bottom.

Use a `;` at the end of every line. Some experts don't do that, but since you're new to programming, follow the rules of the language.

"Learn the rules like a pro so you can break them like an artist."

Lots of learning opportunities below, read my comments and finish the code. Your next challenge is to work some arrays and objects into this code.

```js
function errorChecker(num1, word1, num2, word2) {
  console.log("errorChecker()", num1, word1, num2, word2);
  
  var isValid = true; // we assume valid = true until something bad happens.
  
  if (typeof num1 === "number" && typeof word1 === "string" && typeof num2 === "number" && typeof word2 === "string") {  
    console.log('all parameters are ok');
  } else {
    console.error('parameter error:');
    isValid = false;
  }
  
  var isWord1Good = wordChecker(word1),
      isWord2Good = wordChecker(word2);
      
  if (isWord1Good === true && isWord2Good === true) {
    //don't return here, you have only fulfilled one of your checks.
    //return true;
    console.log("wordChecker says: 'Words are so good.'");
  } else {
    console.error('wordChecker did NOT like', isWord1Good, isWord2Good);
    isValid = false;
  }
  
  //ok do the same thing I did above, I've gotten tired
  if (singularChecker(num1, word1) === false && (pluralChecker(num2, word2) === false)) {
    console.log('correct singular and plurals')
  } else {
    console.log('incorrect singular and plurals')
    isValid = false;    
  }
  
  //Finally return at one point in the function, at the end, this makes it so much easier to debug:
  return isValid;
}

//do similar stuff with this one
// function to set exact word parameters that can be used
function wordChecker (word) {  
  var wordIsTime = false;
  switch (word) {
    case 'seconds':
    case 'second':
    case 'minutes':
    case 'minute':
    case 'hours':
    case 'hour':
    case 'days':
    case 'day':
      wordIsTime = true;      
  }
  
  //here's a log to show what fn you're in, what you sent in, and what it's returning:
  console.log("wordChecker()", word, wordIsTime);
  return wordIsTime;
}

//do similar stuff with this one
function pluralChecker (digit, letters) {
  switch (letters.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'seconds':
    case 'minutes':
    case 'hours':
    case 'days':
      if (digit !== 1) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
  }
}

function singularChecker (numz, wordz) {
  //wordz.lowerCase() is not a function
  switch (wordz.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'second':
    case 'minute':
    case 'hour':
    case 'day':
      if (numz === 1) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
  }
}

// For checking function effectiveness
const num1 = 1;
const word1 = 'minutes';
const num2 = 2;
const word2 = 'minute';


console.log(errorChecker(num1, word1, num2, word2));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback it really helped me.

Comment: You're very welcome! Take a good look at this code. Think about DRY programming: Don't Repeat Yourself.

Are you repeating logic in here? (hint: yes)

Could you combine three functions into one? (hint: absolutely)